# Change Navbar depending on URL

Tags: razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC Core web app that changes from year to year and has test data.  The URLs are (examples):

2017.applicationdomain.com

2018.applicationdomain.com

test.applicationdomain.com

On my _Layout page, I am currently commenting and un-commenting the NAVBAR section just before publishing for each URL (as you can see, the navbar color and brand text changes based on the URL).

See code here:

```
<!--Selector-->
    <!--2017-->
    @*<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark" style="min-height:55px;background-color:#035338">
        <div class="container">
            <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Cashier" asp-action="Index" class="navbar-brand">
                2017 Data
            </a>*@
    <!--Test-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark" style="min-height:55px;background-color:#221958">
        <div class="container">
            <a asp-area="" asp-controller="cashier" asp-action="index" class="navbar-brand">
                test data
            </a>
    <!--2018-->
    @*<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark" style="min-height:55px;">
        <div class="container">
            <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Cashier" asp-action="Index" class="navbar-brand">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="~/images/CUF_Logo1.png" />
            </a>*@
<!--End of Selector-->
```

I want to automate this, without creating too much overhead on my view which will slow it down.  I know I can do a switch statement on a string compare of  `@Context.Request.Host` but I always thought you were supposed to have minimal code on the view, leave the code in the controller.

Anyone have any thoughts on how this can be done server side in the controller rather than all in the view?